# Wrong characters encoding in packaged electron app

Tags: encoding, electron, electron-builder

I have electron app using Vue / Nuxt

Dev build work perfect, but when electron app is packaged then utf-8 characters source files are wrong.

eg `č` is displayed as `Ä` even with default system font.
What is really weird is fact that same wrong character is display even if char is delared
as č in html template. Dev tools displays same malformed string in source instead.
Seems like build step do something wrong with it.

When user input `č` in app or `č` is loaded from external file in runtime, everything is ok.

Comment: [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): UTF-8  byte sequence for `č` is `0xC4,0x8D`  i.e. (interpreted as `latin1` characters)  `Ä` _Latin Capital Letter A With Diaeresis_ followed by  (invisible) _Reverse Line Feed_…

Comment: This still not gives me a clue why is interpreted as latin1. Page itself declares utf-8, data from network in utf-8 is ok.. there must be really something wrong in webpack or electron build steps